# Generalized Taylor derivatives test

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, taylor-expansion

I am seeking for a proof of the generalized derivative test to find inflection points, minima and maxima.
I am seeking for a proof that I read some time ago but can't find anymore. The thesis was that if the first derivative in a point is zero, and also the second derivative is zero, then you have to continue the derivation until you get an n-th derivative with a non-zero value. If that derivative is of an even order, then you have to check if it is positive or negative and subsequently you deduct that it is a minimum or a maximum. If the order of the derivative is odd then it is an inflection point.
The proof used the Taylor formula.
I am sure it is a well known subject and that many questions were asked about this, but I can't find a rigorous complete proof, I found only descriptive talks.
A link to a PDF is also completely okay.
Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: +1 for an interesting piece of trivia I never knew about!

Comment: I hope that this paper: [Generalized local test for local extrema in single-variable functions](https://faculty.utrgv.edu/eleftherios.gkioulekas/papers/submitted/2nd-deriv-gen.pdf) answers your question.

Comment: That is exactly what I was seeking for. In order to close the question, I should provide an answer in the canonic form, so you could you report the link in a complete answer with some sort of insights or I could do it instead. Thanks for your input!